# Continuacion - Lectura de un registro dentro de un repertorio y consultar si tiene un string dado como parte del nombre via Batch Script

Tags: script

Salvo unas pequeñas modificaciones el ejemplo que publicaste me ha servido muchísimo. Bravo, para mi máximo puntaje.
Imagina que tengo nuevamente el repertorioA y el repertorioB(vacío).

> 1).- Se lee el repertorioA y solo hacer la comparación del nombre si se trata de un subrepertorio y no de los ficheros en su interior.

> 2).- Si la comparación es positiva, se tienen que copiar el repertorio y todos los archivos que estén en el interior al repertorioB, pero si en la búsqueda se encuentra un sub-sub-repertorio debe de hacerse la comparacion y hacer lo mismo, copiar el sub-sub-repertorio y su contenido al repertorioB, yo lo he tratado de hacer pero necesito guardarlo en una lista ya que al momento de leer un reperetorio no sé si en el interior existe uno o mas subrepertorios, es decir empezwar el proceso de copiado y eliminación solamente si se sabe que no hay subrepertorios en el interior.

> 3).- Repetir el proceso con todos los subrepertorios de repertorioA.

> 4).- Sé que la pregunta es compleja, de todas maneras yo voy a seguir revisando de mi lado.

Ojalá puedas responder la pregunta Emilio o otra persona. Un abrazo.

Comment: Saludos a Emilio.

Comment: Emilio te buscan